# Get selected multi value data into string

Tags: sharepoint, infopath

I have a field in a sharepoint list which is a look-up from another list.  It is displayed on the infopath form as a multi value checkbox.
I am trying to work out a way to perhaps concat each of the selected items into one string.

For example; the Multi-Value checkbox contains
(! = checked, * = unchecked)

```
! Example A
* Example B
! Example C
```

I would like a new field called MyString to equal "Example A, Example C"

I have tried to do a rule with a button press to query the secondary datasource for the external list, and filter it on the Multi-Value checkbox value.  This works brilliantly for attaining the second column (Dollar Amount) by doing a sum(secondary.amount) with the filter - however I am still unable to work out how to join the selected strings.

Any hints would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You could have a rule on each of those checkboxes that runs when the checkbox is changed. Each rule would look up the other checkbox values, concatenate them how you need it, and set the value of the final MyString textbox field to that string.

Comment: Thanks RoManiac, I did try that - however an issue occurs when you un-check one of the options, the rule doesn't actually trigger when the box is unchecked - there is too much room for error running with that suggestion - thanks for the input tho!